# Recommendations for system to repeatedly force contact between head and desk

Tags: robotic-arm

I frequently bang my head on my desk after performing a task poorly. I would like to eliminate the unnecessary middle step of actually performing a task poorly. As such, I would like to design a system to hold my head and repeatedly strike it against my desk. Alternatively, a system that holds the desk and repeatedly strikes it against my head would be acceptable. Requirements are at least 2 strikes per second maximum with ~50cm travel.

Can anybody make any recommendations for a system to base this device off of? Denso products, while small and affordable, do not have the required load capacity (some users may have a rather large head, and involuntary resistance is to be expected -- at least near the start of the cycle). I am thinking of something more industrial, perhaps:

[image: Fanuc R-2000iA]

Comment: Easier to get a manipulator to grip the head and twist it 360 deg. Problem eliminated.

Comment: According to http://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/1256/32105.0001.001.pdf?sequence=2 p. 186, the range of motion of the human neck is ~77-129 deg. front to back, ~48-86 deg. side-to-side, and ~113-149 deg. around the spinal axis. These lower requirements could potentially reduce cost. A sufficiently advanced system could start with a cycle of strikes, increasing in speed, and end with a rotation. I also seem to recall that the neck can withstand 4kN (900lb) of force along the spinal axis -- I do not know if that is significant for system requirements.

Comment: All righty, get the manipulator to 130 deg pitch, 90 deg yaw and 150 deg roll, followed by a clean strike at 4kN force. Fail safe and efficient.

Comment: Hahahaha, very funny, but it would still be useful if you mention (after the joke) what your real application is. You may receive ideas on how to solve your original problem!